# How to i solve 'Program does not contain a static 'Main' method' for Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, csproj

I upgraded project from `VS2013 (.net framework 4.5)` to `VS2017 (netcoreapp2.0)`.

My project properties looks like simple as following

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

However, when i build i get the error

> Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry
>   point

I looked around to find suitable fix and as per suggestion i added `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`to project properties but still same error i get when build

[check this link](http://www.natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/01/19/project-json-to-csproj/)

[Microsoft guideline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/project-json-to-csproj)

**FYI:** for class libraries e.g. `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">`i don't get this error and it builds fine.

Comment: Add a Main? Can you put the entire project on github?

Comment: Why is main necessary? I actually create website with intentions to put/keep my all client side code e.g. Javascript files, bower, npm, css and html files. In solution i have two websites and multiple class libraries. one website is for holding Server side stuff e.g. controllers and one web site for client side stuff. Probably i can't put entire project on github due to privacy reason

Comment: > Why is main necessary


Because the application is a console application and self hosted. You need to write code to run the server.

Comment: @davidfowl. I understand your point. But it was not the case in VS 2013. The same was treated as 'Class Library' as output. But in VS2017 (dotnetcoreapp2.0) the same is being treated as Console (output type).I just upgraded this website (.net 4.5) from VS2103 to VS2017 (.net core 2.0).

Comment: ASP.NET Core is a differenet beast. I suggest starting here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/.

Comment: Thanks , I shall study definitely. So for, i conclude I  have to have 'Program.cs' for entry point and as well 'Startup.cs' in this Project (i can see it even in the sample projects) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/razor-pages-start

Comment: the .Web sdk is for your program project, not a library. for a library to refer to asp.net core types, you'd need references to the right packages, possibly including `<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />`. or if it really is your endpoint/program project, then it definitely needs a static void main.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to targeting `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, add a property group targeting a library:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>library</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
```